# monitoring call stack size by using ESP pointer

Tags: c++, stack, stack-overflow, cpu-registers

I want to see the call stack size according to the contents of the function.

Therefore, I write the code calling recursive function.

```cpp
void iterative(vector<Integer>& prac){
    int aa=1;
    //double aa=1.1213;
    prac.push_back({100});
    iterative(prac);
}

int main(){
    vector<Integer> chance;
    chance.reserve(100);
    iterative(chance);
    return 0;
}
```

If 'aa' is declared with 'double', I think its call stack size is bigger than the case of 'int'. I think 'int case' ESP pointer value is larger than 'double case'

Therefore, I monitor ESP at eclipse debug mode.

[int case ESP pointer] ... 0x62fdd0 0x62fd90 0x62fd50...

[double case ESP pointer] ... 0x62fdd0 0x62fd90 0x62fd50 ...

As you see, it have same difference value of ESP pointer!

[image]

like this picture, I think the ESP pointer difference should be different accoding to its function contents.

What is my mis-understanding?

Comment: Does your compiler's or your platform's documentation say that there should be a difference?

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't check it. could it have different results according to compilers?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't even have a concept of "stack", much less care about how or if it should be padded.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't know it at all. Thank you so much. Could you give some advice to monitor stack overflow from recursive call? I want to see stack depth that can make stack overflow can change according to its function contents such as local variable.

Comment: It's quite possible that the compiler is optimizing out the unused variable, so the stack frame would be the same size regardless.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to write code that will somehow warn you if you're about to overflow the stack? That's probably not the right solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve. It will require that your code knows how much memory is reserved for your program's stack, and how much of the stack has already been used. You're probably better off understanding why your recursive function is chewing through the stack, and modify your algorithm to prevent that.